# tensorflow 2.0 how create a new tensor geting value of another tensor given a condition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have 2  tensors:

```
h=[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]]

and 

h2=[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 1]]
```

I want to create 3 vector with values where h=h2
I mean ,i want compare h[0]=h2[0] ,h[1]=h2[1]  and h[2]=h2[2]

So I want the 3 vector as:

```
h3=[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
```

I tried :

```
def fn( tensor1,i):
    return tensor1[i]

tensor = [fn(h,i) for i in range(h) if tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(h[i],h2[i])) ]
```

but it return this error TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Answer (score 1):

**Working code snippet**

```
import tensorflow as tf

h=[[0,0 ,0],
   [0, 0 ,1],
   [0, 1 ,0]]

h2=[[0 ,0 ,0],
    [0 ,0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1]]

for i in range(len(h)):
  if tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(h[i],h2[i])):
    print(h[i])
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
```